# Relacion entre String y un tipo de dato

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main()
 {
    int data = -254;
    const size_t BITS = 8*sizeof(data);
    char bin_str[BITS+1];

for(unsigned int i=0;i<BITS; i++)
    {
      unsigned int mask = 1u << (BITS - 1 - i);
      bin_str[i] = (data & mask) ? '1' : '0';
    }
bin_str[BITS] = '\0';

printf("%d:",data);
for(unsigned int i=0; i<BITS;i++)
printf("%c",bin_str[i]);
printf("\n");   
 }
```

¿Cúal es el largo del string de bits que se muestra en pantalla?.
Respuesta según yo: Si no me equivoco es 32.
¿Que relación tiene este valor con el rango de bits del tipo de dato "int" de la variable data?

Comment: ¿ Es época de exámenes o que ? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/396379/19610

Comment: @trauma Sí lo es.

Comment: Duplicada de [¿Relacion entre string y tipo de dato?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/396379/relacion-entre-string-y-tipo-de-dato). ¿Son compañeros de curso con Cristian Soto)? Exactamente el mismo programa.

Comment: Debo hacer un informe junto a mi compañero, si pudieran ayudarnos con la segunda pregunta lo agradeceria mucho, gracias.

Comment: `¿Que relación tiene este valor con el rango de bits del tipo de dato "int" de la variable data?` ... ¡ Pero si lo tenéis puesto en el código ! `BITS = 8 * sizeof( data );`. Creo **sinceramente** que deberías reformular la pregunta :-(